# gwt obfuscated compilation rename

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

We have a project on GWT and our production version have been compiled on obfuscated mode for security reasons. The application works fine, except when a browser plugin inserts javascript on the page, because some plugins have functions with obfuscated names, like aa, ab, xv, zf, etc...

We wonder if there is a way to tell GWT compiler to add a prefix to all javascript obfuscated functions, so the functions get names like cccab, ccczf, cccaa, etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AS far as i'm aware there is no simple way to do this, but it is certanly possible by using GWT linkers: http://webcentersuite.blogspot.cz/2011/05/writing-gwt-linker-for-offline.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way: rewrite the name obfuscator class of GWT compiler and recompile it. I just do it and it works.